# What's the real function for git-stash and git-rebase?

Tags: git

I am studying git, I am confused with some commands issues:

1. I created two branches A and B. In my local repository, A already existed. And Now I want to check out B into the same local repository, and operate at B without disturbing A. So can I check out B without git -stash A? (just moment ago, I just typed checkout B directly, without git -stash A, I think it also can works.Why?) What's the function of git -stash?
2. I have been confused with git -merge and git -rebase. which should I choose at which situation?

Comment: By the way, there's no dash in front of "stash" or "rebase"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stash just stashes away your uncommitted changes so you can work on something else for a while. In the old days, you used to commit your changes, switch branches, switch back, and then use "git reset HEAD^" to reverse your commit.

As for rebase, here are my notes:

Similar to merge, but keeps a single thread of continuity.

In a nutshell, rebase takes the current branch and searches its history for the point where it forked from the specified branch. It then takes all those commits as patches and applies them to the specified branch, effectively transplanting those commits to the end of the specified branch.

before:

```
     E--F--G        mybranch
    /
A--B--C--D          upstream
```

after "rebase upstream":

```
           E'-F'-G' mybranch
          /
A--B--C--D          upstream
```

If there are any commits in both branches (e.g. because you mailed a patch to someone and it was applied), then they don't get applied redundantly.  See man page.

*Note:* This can mess up anybody who already has a copy of your branch.  This command is best used only on commits that haven't been pushed to another repository yet.

*upstream* may be a branch or any other valid commit.

If conflicts are encountered, git adds conflict markers (<<<<<) to the files affected and stops the rebase.  After you resolve a conflict, use "git add *file*".  When all conflicts are dealt with, use "git rebase --continue".  You can also cancel the rebase with "git rebase --abort"

If you have uncommited changes in your current branch, you have to stash them first before doing the rebase.

---

Also allows you to re-write the history of the current branch with the "-i" option (see "Rearrange commits"):

before:

```
A--B--C--D--E
```

after:

```
A--B--E'-C'-D'
```

Or even combine (squash) commits:

```
A--B--CE'-D'
```

Or remove commits from the chain entirely:

```
A--B--D'-E'
```

---

**onto:**

The `--onto branch` option allows you to transplant your changes to a different branch entirely.  For example, suppose your branch was forked from branch 'foo':

```
o--o--o--o--o  master
    \
     o--o--o--o--o  foo
                  \
                   o--o--o  mybranch
```

But now you want it to be forked from master:

```
o--o--o--o--o  master
    \        \
     \        o--o--o  mybranch
      \
       o--o--o--o--o  foo
```

You would check out mybranch and give this command:

```
git rebase --onto master foo
```

In English, this says "take all changes since (but not including) foo, and apply them to master."

--onto can also be used to splice out a commit from the chain.  See the man page.  -i can also be used for this.

---

**Note:** rebase considered harmful: This command works by effectively rewriting history. It's possible to put yourself in a state where it's impossible to reconstruct the state of your repository from some point in the past. For example, in the first example given above, the repository states E, F, and G are now lost forever.

The good news is that if you assign branch names or tags to things before you do the rebase, then nothing is truly lost. If I had done `git branch foo` before doing the rebase, branch "foo" would have pointed to the original state G of the repository, making it recoverable later (until you delete branch foo).

```
       E-F-G   foo
      /
     /     E'-F'-G' mybranch
    /     /
A--B--C--D          upstream
```

Answer (score 2):

`git stash` stores your uncommitted changes. For example, you start working on a feature on branch A, then realize you should be working on branch B, you would do

```
git stash
git checkout B
git stash pop
```

There's a chapter about it in [the book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Rebase/merge is pretty much a matter of opinion. I often prefer rebase. As a rule of thumb, you should never rebase anything that is already made public, because rebase rewrites history.

Answer (score 2):

In english "stash" means "store some where" or "to put away or safe keeping for future use". That's precisely what `git stash` does. If you are working on something but doesn't want to commit it as it's not fully done but need to work on something else urgent, that's when you use `git stash`. Stash your recent changes and branch to the new urgent thing you need to work. For a detailed explanation on what stashing means see [this chapter (6.3 Git Tools - Stashing) in ProGit book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing).

To simply put, rebasing refers to the act of straightening out the history of your work. To fully understand what it means you need to understand what branching is and what merging means. So I would suggest you read [the chapter on branching from the ProGit book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching).